# 〒の言い方は何ですか？ How is 〒 pronounced?

Tags: nuances

誰かに住所を言いたければどうやって郵便記号の文字を言いますか？

例えばこの郵便番号「〒153-0061」の言い方は「何々イチゴサンゼロゼロロクイチ」です。